# If $\int_a^b f(x)dx=\left[F(x)\right]_a^b$, Is $\int_a^b \lvert f(x)\rvert dx= \left[\lvert F(x)\rvert \right]_a^b$ true?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, absolute-value, triangle-inequality

I was brushing up on some basic inequalities and I attempted to derive an alternate form of the regular triangle inequality by using $(\left|b\right|-\left|a\right|)^2$. $$ \begin{align*}(\left|b\right|-\left|a\right|)^2 &= \left|b\right|^2 + \left|a\right|^2 - 2|a||b|\\ &=b^2+a^2-2|a||b|\\ &\leq(b-a)^2\\&=|b-a|^2\end{align*} $$ I arrived at the conclusion that $|b|-|a|\le|b-a| $. This however, does not seem to agree with the following: $$\biggl|\int_{a}^{b} f(x) \, dx\biggr| \leq \int_{a}^{b} |f(x)|\,dx$$ $$\biggr|F(b)-F(a)\biggl| \leq \biggr|F(b)\biggl|-\biggr|F(a)\biggl| $$

Edit: I believe there may be a mistake going from line 3 to line 4.
It should be $|b|-|a| \le (b-a)$  which is only true for $\bigg||b|-|a|\bigg|\le\bigg|b-a\bigg|$.

I was wondering if maybe there was a mistake in my initial derivation or if I am using the absolute value signs incorrectly when applying them to the integrals through the fundamental theorem of calculus. Possibly a condition or assumption I am unaware of. It just seems like an odd result to get and I can't figure out why this is.

Comment: YOur conclusion should be: $|b-a| \ge ||b|-|a||$

Comment: why is that the correct conclusion?

Comment: Did you assume $\int{f(x)}=F(x)+c \implies \int{|f(x)|}=|F(x)|+c$ ?

Comment: Yes. I also assumed that this was for definite integrals only. Is this incorrect?

Comment: I think $\frac{d}{dx}|F(x)|=sgn(F(x))f(x) $

Comment: The given answer is correct; you integrated $|f|$ wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> We know that $|b-a|\geq |b|-|a| $. This however, does not seem to agree with the following: $$\biggl|\int_{a}^{b} f(x) \, dx\biggr| \leq \int_{a}^{b} |f(x)|\,dx\tag{1}$$ $$\biggr|F(b)-F(a)\biggl| \leq \biggr|F(b)\biggl|-\biggr|F(a)\biggl| \tag{2}$$ Where am I going wrong?

We know that equation $(1)$ is correct. It is the equation $(2)$ that has the problems.
If $\int_a^b f(x)dx=\left[F(x)\right]_a^b$, $\int_a^b |f(x)|dx\color{red}{\neq} \left[|F(x)|\right]_a^b$. One has to break the integral to get the latter. For example,
\begin{align*}
\left|\int_{-1}^{+1}x^3\,dx\right|&=\left|\frac14[x^4]_{-1}^{+1}\right|=0\\
\int_{-1}^{+1}|x^3|\,dx=-\int_{-1}^{0}x^3\,dx+\int_{0}^{+1}x^3\,dx=-\frac14[x^4]_{-1}^{0}+\frac14[x^4]_{0}^{+1}=\frac12&\color{red}{\neq}\frac14[|x^4|]_{-1}^{+1}=0\\
\end{align*}